# Minimum Distance between two magnetic rotary encoders in an array : AMS [AS5048B]

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, magnetics, encoder, rotary-encoder

I am planning to prototype with multiple [AS5048B](https://ams.com/as0548b) sensors. (Very basic: Magnets are horizontally placed over the IC that the IC can detect and give an angular reading). I plan to create an array of sensors and magnets shown below.

**EDIT:** I wanted to make an array of these sensors instead of making 24 pcbs individually, hence the question of minimum distance. The geometry, and the placement of sensors is exactly as illustrated in the images below

[image: Test Board]

[image: Minimum Distance between sensors]

[image: AS5048B Sensor]

However, I do not know the minimum distance that the ICs need to be placed from each other to get minimum distortion of readings, as the magnets will move independently of each other during operation. The purpose of this is to do performance testing of the ICs and the control loop that is running.

Comment: It depends on the shape of your magnet and their arrangements. Page 31 and 32 of the datasheet state that the distance of the magnet can be (vertically) 0.5 to 2.5mm with a strength of 30-70mT. I would say that the question would remain unclear, until you include more information on the geometry of what you are trying to measure. EDIT: Why do you need an array of these sensors? Is this an x-y platform of some kind etc.?

Comment: Consider soft iron (start with tin plate but there's always Mu-metal) walls between rows of magnets if Y axis separation isn't enough. X axis is probably fine.

Comment: @Syed, yes, it is similar to an xy platform I guess, the geometry,etc are exactly as in the picture. These simple serve as an I2C line of slave devices and since I am using theses sensors itself, I wanted to make an array of these sensors instead of making 24 pcbs individually, hence the question of minimum distance. (I have included this detail in the question now)

Comment: I dont think there is a "hard" limit for minimum distance, you will probably just get some interference from the other fields which will show up as some noise in the readings.

Comment: @WesleyLee I hope that is the case, however, it decides the design descion of future projects as well, where I might need to place these sensors at.